# The system cannot execute the specified program in visual studio

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I have windows 10, and visual studio 2017, target framework is 4.5.1.

I wrote a simple console app, that only prints "Hello world", but when I run the output says:

`The system cannot execute the specified program`

Please give some advises.

Comment: Have you targeted the right architecture? (x86, x64)

Comment: I tried x64, x86 ang "Any CPU", still don't work :/

Comment: Have you installed the framework, etc dotnet core or dotnet framework runtime?

Comment: Yes, all installed, plz tell why the downvote? what's wrong with the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your anti virus settings, that’s might be the issue.